# Data not insert in database

Tags: php

```
<?php      
include('config_contact.php');
// fetching admin email where mail will send
$sql ="SELECT emailId from tblemail";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if($query->rowCount() > 0):
  foreach($results as $result):
    $adminemail=$result->emailId;
  endforeach;
endif;

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  // getting Post values    
  $name=$_POST['name'];
  $phoneno=$_POST['phonenumber'];
  $email=$_POST['emailaddres'];
  $subject=$_POST['subject'];
  $message=$_POST['message'];
  $uip = $_SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $isread=0;
  // Insert query
  $sql="INSERT INTO  tblcontactdata(FullName,PhoneNumber,EmailId,Subject,Message,UserIp,Is_Read) VALUES(:fname,:phone,:email,:subject,:message,:uip,:isread)";
  $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  // Bind parameters
  $query->bindParam(':fname',$name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->bindParam(':phone',$phoneno,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->bindParam(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->bindParam(':subject',$subject,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->bindParam(':message',$message,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->bindParam(':uip',$uip,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->bindParam(':isread',$isread,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->execute();
  $lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();}
```

Comment: Please edit your post, select your code and press on the brackets "Code sample" to make it better readable

Comment: Would you please explain a little more what you're trying to do, what doesn't work and maybe add any error messages you get instead of just dumping your code here? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What's your question about all this code?

Comment: @NicoHaase I think the question is "Why doesn't insertion into the database work?" Where is the mistake? "

Comment: Did you tested POST result? `if(isset($_POST)){ var_dump($_POST);} else{ echo"NO POST";}